# How to spend html code to javascript string

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to append a html code to js string. How can i achieve it.

So basically I want the string to look like this

```
A
B
```

For this purpose I have written the below code.

`var a= ''
a= 'A' + <br> + 'B'`

How ever I don't get the desired output. Can anyone help me in solving this.

`return a`

Comment: How are you trying to output the string, and where to?

Answer (score 0):

html is a text format. The markup is rendered by the browser, and relevant processors. Your error is to think of the markup as code and write it as if the markup tags are keywords(which they are for dedicated processors). 
So the solution to your problem is to put the `<br>` in the parentheses and get rid of the concatenation: `'A<br>B'`